# Remove difference but keeping order and duplicates in python lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using version 3.x - want to know simplest and native way to solve the following:

Example lists:

```
listA = [1, 2, 3, 66, 0]
listB = [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 66, 0, 99, 0, 3]
```

How do I remove the difference between 2 lists so that a new listC becomes same as listA with the exact same order?

So using the example above the listC should equal `[1, 2, 3, 66, 0]`

List A could be bigger than list B and the other condition is that List A will never have in repeat numbers unlike list B which could have duplicates.

The charity club exercise I'm trying to solve is:

Linday's brain test:

Please write a program that prints ’YES’ if elements of B occur in A in the order they appear in B but not necessarily consecutively. Otherwise the program should print ’NO’.

Linday's bonus test:

Please write a program that prints ’YES’ if elements of B occur in A in the
order they appear in B and consecutively.

Obviously if anyone fancies the challenge then kindly post complete programs to solve these 2 questions.

Comment: Linday's brain test just asks whether B is a **subsequence** of A, right?

Comment: You write: *"List B will never have in repeat numbers unlike list A whist [sec] could have duplicates."*: but the example you give violates this condition: *listB* has duplicates in your example.

Comment: I've corrected that mistake but Trincot your solution worked for the first part thank you really well layout and simple. Can you kindly re post the bonus question solution

Comment: I am rewriting some of it. Will repost when done ;-) But: the Lindsay brain/bonus questions seem to suggest that A will often have more elements than B. If B has more than A, then neither can return "YES", if I read it well, since *every* element of B must occur in A, keeping the same order. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: Another question. The Lindey tests say *"..prints ’YES’ if elements of B occur in A.."*. Does this mean *all* elements of B? Or is one enough? But if one is enough than it is meaningless to request that it appears in the same order in A. If one is enough the algorithm could stop checking anything else, and just print "YES". Or should it still check further, and if there is a second element from B that occurs in A, but in the wrong order, it should still print "NO"? I find the description confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach that cheats only slightly is to make use of strings with the `in` operator.  If you convert each list into a string, you can quickly see if A is a substring of B in the same order and **consecutively**.

```
def aInB(listA, listB):
    str_a = "," + ",".join([str(c) for c in listA]) + ","
    # ',1,2,3,66,0,'
    str_b = "," + ",".join([str(c) for c in listB]) + ","
    # ',0,0,1,2,3,66,0,99,0,3,'

    return str_a in str_b
# True
```

Now this only works if the length of A is less than B but by the definition of the problem, it sounds like that is always true.  The extra commas are necessary because of the problem pointed out by @stefanpochmann in the comments.

Getting this to print "YES" and "NO" is very straightforward:

```
if aInB(listA, listB):
   print("YES")
else:
   print("NO")
```

For the non-consecutive approach, I believe you would have to do one of the iterative approaches. This solution is here to simply provide an alternative way of thinking about is "A in B".

EDIT:  I couldn't help myself, so here is an interactive approach that is probably way overkill, but maybe you'll find it easier to understand (you never know).

```
def aInB(listA, listB):
   # if listA is empty, don't even bother
   if not listA:
      return False

   # build a dictionary where each key is a character in listA
   # and the values are a list containing every index where that character
   # appears in listB
   occurences = {c:[i for i,e in enumerate(listB) if e==c] for c in listA}

   # now we are going to walk through listA again
   # but this time we are going to use our `occurences` dictionary
   # to verify that the elements appear in order
   last_index = 0
   for i,e in enumerate(listA):
     # if the character `e` never appears in listB
     # then it will have an empty list
     # and we can return False
     if not occurences[e]:
         return False

     # now the next possible index for the next character in listA
     # must be *greater* than the index of the last character we found
     # if no such index exists, then listA is not contained within listB
     # if it is, we update the last seen index
     next_possible_index = [x for x in occurences[e] if x > last_index]
     if not next_possible_index:
         return False
     last_index = next_possible_index[0]

   # if we make it out of the for loop
   # then all is well, and listA is contained in listB
   # but not necessarily consequtively 
   return True
```

Comment: Fails for example `aInB([1], [11])`.

Comment: Good catch.  There's a fix for that though.

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(l1, l2):
    i1 = 0
    i2 = 0

    while i1 < len(l1) and i2 < len(l2):
        if l1[i1] == l2[i2]:
            i1 += 1
            i2 += 1
        else:
            i2 += 1

    if i1 == len(l1):
        return True
    return False

listA = [1, 2, 3, 66, 0]
listB = [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 66, 0, 99, 0, 3]

print (f(listA, listB))
# will print true
```

Comment: Ok you're obviously a smart guy - how do I actually use this in the same program without creating this function?

Comment: Sorry, this is just an idea to solve the probleme that should print 'YES' or 'NO'

Comment: Why do you not want to create a function?

Comment: I think if you want to remove the function, just remove the the first line and change the return to a print statment

Comment: Thanks - your one looks sooo complex! I've made errors just copying it!!

Comment: No problem, but if you look more closely you will see that my solution is very simple in fact ;)

Comment: how do actually print out the listC? I don't think the code works correct as it prints true based on the len and not content. Is there a way to add a sanity check so that we see it print out "listC"?

Comment: This code is just to print Yes or no, not to print the listC.  You can easily patch it to do so. Add l=[] before the loop, and l.append(l1[i1]) in the if. Then return l in place of true and false